# MySql Trigger not created. Syntax error:#1064

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with trigger in MySql. When i create a trigger i have a syntax error

```
 CREATE TABLE user (
 id int NOT NULL,
 completeName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 passw_hash varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 accType varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
 create or REPLACE trigger test
 AFTER insert on user
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,'Pinco 
 Pallo','pinco@pallo','zinco','Owner');
 end;
```

Erorr:#1064

Comment: Please add the exact error message to the question, specifically the part after `near ...`

Comment: You cannot insert into the table where the trigger is defined on. Describe the task itself.

Comment: What problem is this trigger intended to solve..as is it is you appear want to create a duplicate row or possibly reuse a deleted id or update an existing id

Comment: As the first comment mentions, please add the FULL error message to the question. The second comment is also correct that you cannot act on the _same table_ that fires the trigger, because it would cause a recursive situation. Know that defining a trigger typically requires changing the `DELIMITER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors in shown code.

1. MySQL does not support `OR REPLACE` in `CREATE TRIGGER`.

It allows to use `CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS` which forbids the trigger creation if it exists already. If you want to replace trigger then you must drop it then recreate.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-trigger.html

2. Trigger cannot alter the table which it is defined on.

Trigger will be created. But it will cause *Can't update table 'user' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.* runtime error.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html